# swift fast enumeration on MDLAsset not working

Tags: ios, swift

I load an MDLAsset from my main bundle and get an compile error when fast iterating the asset object.

```
Type 'MDLAsset' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

Documentation says it does support fast enumeration:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ModelIO/Reference/MDLAsset_Class/

Iterating over the asset is rather simple

```
for obj in asset {
    ...
}
```

I am using XCode7.1.1 and Swift2, is there something broken or what is it I am doing wrong?